# Using a key within a map

Tags: dictionary, groovy, key

I have this function:

```
def getMap(value = null) {
    [
        "SomeTitle": [ Param: 9, Size: 2, Default: 150, Val: value ]
    ]
}
```

and I can use `getMap(152).SomeTitle.Val`

What I want to do is use the key `Size` while calculating the Key `Val`, something like:

```
def getMap(value = null) {
    [
        "SomeTitle": [ Param: 9, Size: 2, Default: 150, Val: value * Size ]
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use the Value of a Key within a map as a variable while calculating the Value of a another Key

This in Java/Groovy

Comment: Is there a reason you want to get the value from another map entry rather than a local method variable?

Comment: Size is part of the map and has to be used to calculate the value, instead of defining 2 in 2 places, I want to reduce the chances of errors for very large maps

Comment: You could use the local method variable to populate more than one entry of the map `[Size: size, Val: size * value]`, so I wouldn't regard it as defining it in two places.

Comment: Yes it is defining in 2 places, when someone needs to change the code tomorrow they need to make 2 modifications and my goal is to avoid that (six sigma principles)

Comment: You'd only need to change the value of size in one place. `int size = 2; [Size: size, val: size * value]`

Comment: You're right it could work for one entry, I have about 50 entries, it would be difficult to manage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy can't autoreference the map on it's initialization, but you can use a `with {}` method to do some post-initialization processing:

```
def getMap(value = null) {
    [
        "SomeTitle": [ Param: 9, Size: 2, Default: 150 ].with {
            put('Val', value * get('Size'))
            it
        }
    ]
}


assert getMap(10).SomeTitle.Val == 20
```

Comment: Hey! When you use the `with`, every method invoked in the closure will be delegated to the map, but the `with` method itself doesn't return the map; instead, it will return whatever is in the last line. The `it` is our map, so we want it returned.